# Sql Sum function giving different data every time running query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table  A , containing Column [GL_Amount]  of datatype  varchar
 GL_Amount contain following  data :: -856.32 ,-261.60 ,-15.04 ,537.11

When  I apply below query  ::

```
Select Count(Cast(GL_Amount as  Float)) From TableA
```

So, every time  i run this query i get different result.

I need to correct this thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TRY THIS**

```
SELECT SUM(Convert(Money, GL_Amount)) GL_Amount
FROM TableA
```

Answer (score 2):

You probbaly want to `sum`.

```
Select SUM(Cast(GL_Amount as  decimal(10,2))) 
From TableA
```

And `float` is inaccurate. Use a fixed-point data type like [**decimal**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html). Or use an automatic conversion

```
Select SUM(GL_Amount * 1.0) 
From TableA
```

Comment: Getting  Error ::  Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

Comment: How big are your numbers and your sum? Try using `*1`

Comment: when try to convert '368715.26' * 1  then error ::  cannot  able to convert into int